# Circular linked list crashes when displayed

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to make a circular linked list. When I try to display the list after creating it, the program keeps on crashing. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;

node * createList(int);
void display(node * head);

int main() {
    struct node * head;

    head = createList(5);
    display(head);

}

node * createList(int n) {

    int i = 0,data = 0;
    struct node * head = NULL;
    struct node * temp = NULL;
    struct node * p = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data++;
        temp->next = head;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL) {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void display(node * head) {
    struct node * temp = head->next;
    while (temp != head) {
        printf("%d-> \t",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: Explain this line of code: `temp->next = head;`  What is its goal?  (It leads to `while (p->next != NULL) {` looping forever.)

Comment: You won't have a `while (p->next != NULL)` in a circular list --- the last node->next pointer points to the head node (hence a circular list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have set every `temp`'s `next` to `head` in `temp->next = head;` but did it too early (the first is just `NULL`). Then you tested `p->next` against `NULL` in `while (p->next != NULL) {` but you should have tested against `head`. Alternatively, you can continue to test against `NULL` but then you need to initialize `temp->next` to `NULL` and assign `head` to `temp->next` only after the for loop.
2. Your display code started from the second link.

Here is a fixed code using the first option in `1.` above:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data++;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != head) {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
        temp->next = head;
    }
```

Here is a fixed code using the alternative option in `1.` above. You still need to initialize `temp->next` to `NULL` since `malloc()` does not  initialize.

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data++;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL) {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = head;
    }
```

But in reality, there is no need to "walk" from the head on every creation. You can simply keep the previous and link it to the next:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data++;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = p = temp;
        } else {
            p = p->next = temp;
        }
    }
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = head;
    }
```

Here is a fix for the `display()`:

```
void display(node * head) {
    struct node * temp = head;
    if (temp != NULL) {
        do {
            printf("%d-> \t",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        } while (temp != head);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried your code and it's still crashing :/

Comment: @VenoM I've also initialized `temp->next` to `NULL`, try now

Comment: Yep, adding temp->next = NULL did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the first node you initialize:

```
    struct node *head = NULL;
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ...
        temp->next = head;
```

So `tmp->next == NULL` on the first iteration leaving `head->next == NULL`. That will not work for a circular list. When you attempt to insert the 2nd node:

```
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL) {
```

What was `head->next` again?? (oh, `NULL`) Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (BOOM Segfault!)

Do your circular list correctly. On insertion of the first node set:

```
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
            head->next = temp;              /* you must set head->next to temp */
        } ...
```

So on the insertion of the remaining nodes you simply need:

```
        } else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != head) {       /* iterate to last node */
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;                 /* now set p->next = temp */
        }
```

Now, you handle your `display()` function the same way, e.g.

```
void display (node *head)
{
    if (!head) {                            /* validate list not empty */
        puts ("(list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    struct node *temp = head;
    
    do {                                    /* same loop problem fixed in display() */
        printf ("%d-> \t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != head);
    
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

If you make the changes, then you can test your list with:

```
int main (void) {
    struct node *head, *tmp;

    head = createList(5);
    display (head);

    puts ("\niterate from mid-list");
    tmp = head;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    display (tmp);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lls_circular_fix
0->     1->     2->     3->     4->

iterate from mid-list
2->     3->     4->     0->     1->
```

Lastly, you are not multiplying the type `node` by `head` in `struct node * head = NULL;` Write it as `struct node *head = NULL;` (the same for all your function declarations as well) Much more readable.

When you go to delete a note from the list, you must create a special case for both `head` and `tail` (the last node). In this sense, the singly-linked list takes a bit more effort than a doubly-linked list due to not having a `prev` node pointer to track the prior node.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

A full example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *createList (int);
void display (node *head);

int main (void) {
    struct node *head, *tmp;

    head = createList(5);
    display (head);

    puts ("\niterate from mid-list");
    tmp = head;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    display (tmp);
}

node *createList (int n)
{
    int i = 0,data = 0;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    struct node *p = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!(temp = malloc (sizeof *temp))) {
            perror ("malloc-temp");
            return NULL;
        }
        temp->data = data++;
        temp->next = head;                  /* head is NULL on 1st node insertion */

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
            head->next = temp;              /* you must set head->next to temp */
        } else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != head) {       /* iterate to last node */
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;                 /* now set p->next = temp */
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void display (node *head)
{
    if (!head) {                            /* validate list not empty */
        puts ("(list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    struct node *temp = head;
    
    do {                                    /* same loop problem fixed in display() */
        printf ("%d-> \t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != head);
    
    putchar ('\n');
}
```